# What is an easy way to display graphs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, graph, sparklines

I am looking at some graphing options, and would like one that has the cleanliness of Sparklines gem but that doesn't require Rmagick.  I'd like one with some clear tutorials, too.

Comment: I asked a similar question, but I never got a suitable answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723497/

Comment: Does the output need to be an image file (e.g. can it be flash/javascript/...)?

Comment: hmm I'm flexible -- for me -- easy of use is the primary concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts as a possible solution.

Comment: I liked highcharts...seems like a possibility.  debating between that an google

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with Rmagick?  I'm just thinking a little more info might help, but because of that restriction I guess my answer probably won't suit you either--I'd say switch to JRuby and use any of the packages available on the jvm.

Comment: Rmagick has been too difficult to install with all the dependencies, I am developing on windows 7 64-bit and it looks like the package is 32 bit...and then I deploy to heroku....it seems like alot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I use win32ole to get Excel to create graphs. Probably more suitable if you're on a desktop rather than a web server.